# Jekyll/Kramdown image location in file system

Tags: image, jekyll, kramdown

I'm using Jekyll with Kramdown on Github, and I want to insert an image in my page. So I use

```
![img1](img1.jpg)
```

and include `img1.jpg` in the folder `_posts`

The generated HTML is

```
<p> <img src="img1.jpg" alt="img1" /> </p>
```

but then the link is

```
http://username.github.io/projectname/2017/04/27/img1.jpg
```

and this link does not exist. How can I correct it?

Comment: You can create a `images` directory and add your image in there. Change the markdown to `![img1](images/img1.jpg)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put image somewhere else (e.g. `/images/` directory) and then insert it as `![img1](/images/img1.jpg)`.